# error trying to get a document from firebase using UID, Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting 2 error in my code trying to get a document from a Firebase collection `/users` using UID,
base on this document [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read)

**First one =>** error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at [calfran_app] lib/pages/home.dart:49)`

**Second one** => error: Undefined name 'users'. (undefined_identifier at [calfran_app] lib/pages/home.dart:37)

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('user.uid').snapshots();


    int _currentIndex = 0;

    final tabs = [

      //TAB DE MANUAIS
      Center(
          child: (Scaffold(

              body:  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: users.snapshots(), 
                   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Something went wrong');
                    }

                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text("Loading");
                    }

                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: ListView(
                       snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {


                            var dio = Dio();

                            return Card(
                              color: Colors.grey[250],
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    new Image.asset(
                                      'Images/pdflogo.png', width: 32,
                                    ),
                                    Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        (document.data()['nome'].toString()),
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),

                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    ButtonBar(
                                      children: <Widget>[

                                        FlatButton(
                                            child: const Text(
                                                'Compartilhar / Download'),
                                            onPressed: () async {
                                              var request = await HttpClient()
                                                  .getUrl(Uri.parse(
                                                  document.data()['documento']));
                                              var response = await request
                                                  .close();
                                              Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(
                                                  response);
                                              await Share.file(
                                                  'ESYS AMLOG',
                                                  'Manual.pdf',
                                                  bytes,
                                                  'image/jpg');
                                            }),


                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ));
                  })))),
```

Comment: the second error is there no stream name users you have to change it with documentStream

Comment: stream: documentStream,

Comment: for the first can you precise what is in line 49 of home.dart

Comment: your stream is Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('user.uid').snapshots();

Comment: you mean stream: documentStream.users.snapshots(), ???

Comment: so to call it you should call with it name so change stream: users.snapshots(),  to stream: documentStream

Comment: ohh ok, stream: documentStream, it worked

Comment: sorry Im newbie at developing app, so in the line 49 i want to display PDF files, base on the document UID , each user should see their specific document , Im using a list view because  the user can have more than one pdf file.

Comment: can you specifie what is in the line 49

Comment: 47 return Container(
                     48 padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                     49 child: new ListView(
                       50 snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {

Comment: you have to user ListView.builder